# Updated state value is not reflected inside setInterval() in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following:

```
const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(false);
const myTimer = useRef(null);

const startTimer = () => {
  myTimer.current = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(isPaused); // always says "false"
  }, 1000);
};
```

Elsewhere in the code while this timer is running I'm updating the value of `isPaused`:

```
setIsPaused(true);
```

But this isn't reflected in the console log, it always logs false. Is there a fix to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `myTimer.current` never changed which means `isPaused` is always `false` inside the function.

You need to make use of `useEffect` to update `myTimer.current` every time `isPaused` is updated.

```
useEffect(() => {
  function startTimer() {
    myTimer.current = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(isPaused);
    }, 1000);
  };
  
  startTimer();
  return () => clearInterval(myTimer.current); // cleanup
}, [isPaused]);
```

Comment: Thanks! just so I understand what's happening here, when isPaused's value is changed you are creating a new interval and clearing the old one each time right?

Also Is it possible to define this the same as before somehow as a value of `startTimer` so that I can call it like so `startTimer()`?

Comment: Yes, you got it right. `useEffect()` will clear out the timer every after render (when `isPaused` changed, see the `[isPaused]` is a dependency of the effect). Yes. You can put `startTimer()` inside the `useEffect()` as well. see updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
  const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(false);
  const myTimer = useRef(null);

  const startTimer = () => {
    myTimer.current = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(isPaused); // now updates
    }, 1000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    startTimer();
    return () => myTimer.current != null && clearInterval(myTimer.current);
  }, [isPaused]);

  return (
    <div>
      <b>isPaused: {isPaused ? "T" : "F"}</b>
      <button onClick={() => setIsPaused(!isPaused)}>Toggle</button>
    </div>
  );
```

#### Use Others function

use `useInterval` from [30secondsofcode](https://www.30secondsofcode.org/react/s/use-interval)

```
const Timer = props => {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = React.useState(0);
  useInterval(() => {
    setSeconds(seconds + 1);
  }, 1000);

  return <p>{seconds}</p>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Timer />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Or, use [react-useInterval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-useinterval) package

```
function Counter() {
  let [count, setCount] = useState(0);
 
  const increaseCount = amount => {
    setCount(count + amount);
  };
 
  useInterval(increaseCount, 1000, 5);
  return <h1>{count}</h1>;
}
```

Comment: The `useEffect()` will run every after render not when `isPaused` is changed.